# Force open AR Quicklook links through Safari mobile browser

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

People who have been keeping up with the new ARKit features will know that AR QuickLook is a new feature introduced with ARKit 2.0 that lets you try AR features right inside your browser instead of installing a separate AR app.

The issue I am facing is that when I share a webpage containing AR QuickLook enabled products to my friends on facebook, it opens up the link through Facebook/whichever apps internal webview browser instead of Safari and because the webpage isn't viewed through Safari browser in the iPhone, the QuickLook links don't work. That is they simply show the picture and no AR badge.

You can test this out by opening the offical Apple QuickLook Page in Facebooks browser in your iPhone. 
https://developer.apple.com/arkit/gallery/

**My question is if there is a way to make a link open only through the safari browser by default instead of opening it through the apps own webview.**

It is in my opinion clear that AR QuickLook will excel as a social feature enabling people to share AR products with their friends for them to view it. However, it does not seem very optimal that when sharing these links to others through any social media mobile app, these links don't do their intended functionality.

Comment: AR QuickLook is an extension that runs inside a hosting app, and Safari View Controller is itself an extension (or remote process) hosted by an app — I wouldn't be surprised if there were some issues related to the double-remote-hosting. Regardless, it's probably a good idea to bring this up as a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).